# Clustering or classification to demonstrate that a yeast disease model is similar to a human disease

Tags: r, classification, clustering, pca

I have a yeast model which is suppose to model a human disease. We ran an experiment to determine gene expression in this model, and have list of genes that were differentially expressed between the disease model versus the wildtype counterpart.

What I'd like to do is say that this set of significantly altered genes can be used to classify/sort human data. So ideally, for example say there were 200 genes. If I plug these genes in a human set, it would be nice to show that I can differentiate between the samples with or without the disease.

What I've done so far is a supervised `hclust` and `PCA` using this set of 200 genes, but so far this has not been successful.  I'm wondering if anyone has any other ideas? It would be great if there was an R example, but it's not necessary.

Comment: hclust and PCA are unsupervised models. What do you mean by "supervised hclust and PCA?" Do you mean canonical correlation analysis?

Comment: its "supervised" in that only a subset of a selective set of genes were used to run the clustering